# importing CV_MEDIAN to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, image-processing

I'm new to opencv using java. I used tutorials to configure opencv with eclipse and now, I want to use it to apply the Median filter on my image. I have imported :

```
import  org.opencv.*;
import  org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.*;
```

and to make sure I'm imported CV_MEDIAN itself. but I'm getting this error when it comes to importing CV_MEDIAN.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type CV_MEDIAN cannot be resolved to a variable HoughTransform.java

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.CV_MEDIAN cannot be resolved

Any idea what might be wrong ?!

Answer (score 0):

org.opencv.imgproc is the package, org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc is a static class.

while you can import a class, you cannot import the content of it (e.g. constants or static functions)

so your import should look like this:

```
import org.opencv.imgproc.*;

// then use:
Imgproc.CV_MEDIAN
```